# sequence of images of my sprite hurt performance

Tags: iphone, xcode, performance, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

so I have a sprite that I create every second on the screen. This sprite is a sequence of 20 images . I would like to know if it can hurt performance ? if yes how can I reduce the impact on the performance thank you :) sorry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: Are you saving each image in it's own file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked with sprites before and yes the more you have on the screen the lower your performance will be. The sequence of 20 images part is what worries me. Instead of using 20 images, look into something called a spritesheet.

A spritesheet is where all your images (an animation In your case right??) are in one file and you keep some parameters stored like

-How big is one frame?

-How many frames?

-X and Y positions.

Example: If I have a 5 frame animation, and each image is 20x100 pixels. I would put them all in one image file side by side, making the image file 100x100. I would draw each portion of this spritesheet on the screen in sequential order.

So my parameters would be:

-SizePerFrame = (20, 100)

-TotalSizeOfImage = (100, 100)

-FramesTotal = 5

-x y of First frame = (0,0)

So I would draw a portion from (0,0) to (20,100) first frame, (20,100) to (40,100) the second and so on.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: thank you . so a sprite sheet is much more better for performance ?

Comment: well the concept of a sprite sheet in general is cleaner, and should boost performance. However like I mentioned above, which should be obvious, the more animations on the screen the lower the performance. I've had fun in the past blasting thousands of animated sprites onto the screen and watching it screech to a halt. You'll also be more limited on a mobile platform like iPhone.